# How to use specific Java version from a conda environment inside of Jupyter notebook

Tags: java, r, azure, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

My overall aim is to use `sparklyr` within an R Jupyter notebook on my Azure cloud service of Jupyter lab. I created a new conda environment with R, sparklyr and Java 8 (since this is the version supported by sparklyr) as follows:

```
conda create -n r_spark r=3.6 r-essentials r-irkernel openjdk=8 r-sparklyr
source activate r_spark
R
> IRkernel::installspec(user=TRUE, name="rspark", displayname="R (Spark)")
```

When I run R **within a terminal** session within this environment, everything works fine:

```
R
> system("java -version")
openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b12, mixed mode)
> library(sparklyr)
> sc <- spark_connect(master="local")
* Using Spark: 2.3.3
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'openssl':
  method      from
  print.bytes Rcpp
> spark_disconnect(sc)
NULL
>
```

However, when I do the same **within a notebook** with the very same "R (Spark)"-kernel, it uses Java openjdk version 11:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master="local")
Error in validate_java_version_line(master, version): Java version detected
but couldnt parse version from: openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
Traceback: [...]
```

Furthermore `system("java -version", intern=TRUE)` returns an empty result from within the notebook.

How can I tell the notebook to use the Java version from its environment?

Comment: I have limited experience with notebooks, know nothing about R, and have never even heard of `sparklyr` so take everything I say with a grain of salt, but: where do you launch Jupyter from? I would guess that for Jupyter to find the openjdk in your evironment you'd have to launch Jupyter from *that* env, however your `conda create` command suggests that you're launching it from somewhere else.

Comment: actually, the jupyter notebooks are launched from a dedicated service on the Azure cloud called "Jupyter Lab". Since i create conda envs within this jupyter web browser gui, I guess it's part of the problem...

Comment: In the notebook, does `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")` correctly point to the Java in the env? Are there any config options for `sparklyr` that allow setting the Java path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@merv's comment put me on the right track:

Get the current `JAVA_HOME`-path with `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")` in the R console in the terminal within the environment: `"/path/to/your/java"`.

In the notebook with the corresponding environment kernel, use `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/path/to/your/java")` and go!